# CSS suddenly stopped working on github pages deployment. (tailwind)

Tags: html, css, deployment, github-pages

It was working fine till the latest commit. But now css is not working on github pages deployment. locally its working fine. Here is the link to repo-
https://github.com/ilyasbabu/questio-bank-django

Comment: maybe you can delete the repository and then rebuild it

Comment: @AdhiArdiansyah thats not the solution!!!

Comment: sometimes it happens to me. i was trying to fix but its not working, same as you locally works fine. And the final solution for me is rebuild the repository

Comment: @AdhiArdiansyah but all the commits and all will be lost right?

Comment: yes, but your local files won't lost. And you have to delete .git folder in your local file and recommit from the beginning

Comment: @ilyasbbu CSS is working fine for the website you mentioned.

Comment: @Kundan yeah now it worked i just rebuild tailwind and commmited again so it worked, but i dont know why this happened!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.